# Android Studio - Errors after adding Google Play Services / Android Support

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

First I copied and placed

- google-play-services.jar in my "src/main/libs/" folder
- android-support-v4.jar in my "src/main/libs/" folder

I then for both did this:

- Right clicked on top root item (project)
- Selected "Module Settings"
- Navigated to "Dependencies"
- Clicked "+" and "File Dependency"
- Chose "google-play-services.jar" and "android-support-v4.jar"

> However, I now get this error:
>
> Execution failed for task ':standard:dexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
> >       D:\DevTools\android-studio-intellij\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\dx.bat
> >     --dex --output W:\intellij-android-projects\EXAMPLE\standard\build\libs\standard-debug.dex
> >     W:\intellij-android-projects\EXAMPLE\standard\build\classes\debug
> >     W:\intellij-android-projects\EXAMPLE\standard\build\dependency-cache\debug
> >     W:\intellij-android-projects\EXAMPLE\standard\build\pre-dexed\debug\android-support-v4-b111dc7043c3c79f72d7939f47909b3747170302.jar
> >     W:\intellij-android-projects\EXAMPLE\standard\build\pre-dexed\debug\classes-cd6929ed4c5651a3b535fb10f1d69394208e6d09.jar
> >     W:\intellij-android-projects\EXAMPLE\standard\build\pre-dexed\debug\google-play-services-806451f099bfcf85b10dd770cda9957922315e35.jar
> >     W:\intellij-android-projects\EXAMPLE\standard\build\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.0.1-1f8b441cc636851c8231d692429070254dbba449.jar
> >     Error Code:   2 Output:   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
> >       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
> >     Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
> >           at
> >     com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
> >           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
> >           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
> >           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
> >           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)         at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
> >           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)      at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)      at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)         at
> >     com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

My %project%/build.gradle file looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

My %project%/%module%/build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile files('src/main/libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: you should add the other build.gradle, which is placed in your main module's folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check your module dependencies and build.gradle file to verify that you do not already have a dependency on the Android v4 support libs via the Maven repository:

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}`

The default behavior of Android Studio is to add this to new projects or ones which have been migrated from Eclipse.  It looks like the tool is picking that up as well as the JAR file you manually added to the `libs` directory.

Comment: Looking at my build.gradle file, it appears that was not the error. I am new to IntelliJ, soo May have added the .jars wrong I suppose? (I did try follow instrucions I found in another SO though)

Comment: Check the build.gradle file under your app's module directory rather than the one at the top level.  For example, if your app project is called `MyApp` and your activity module is at `MyApp/app` with the `src/main` living under that `app` directory, look for a separate `build.gradle` file in that directory.  The one you posted is the `build.gradle' file from the top level project directory.

Comment: In general you really should use the Maven-style includes for dependencies, like the answer shows here, instead of copying jar files around. The Gradle build system is smarter about avoiding duplicates with Maven-style includes. You can add these includes through the Module Dependencies dialog; you don't have to do it manually. If you upgrade Android Studio, later versions provide more assistance about adding dependencies to common libraries such as support and play-services.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer I have no posted the content of that build.gradle file as well. It appears the dependencies are pointing to the .jar files. Should I change the gradle file to looks like yours?

Comment: @ScottBarta Thanks - I will try to remember that. Does that mean I do nott have to copy the .jar files to each project any longer? I can simply point Android Studio to my repository for .jar files, and it Android Studio will do the copying and configuration itself?

Comment: I believe the problem you are seeing is because you're using the Maven style dependency for the v7 support library, which itself depends on the v4 support library.  So you should not need the 
`dependencies {
...
    compile files('src/main/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
`
Try removing that line in your dependency list.  You should also be able to replace the Google play services with a Maven style dependency, as Scott Suggested.

Comment: @Tom, I just verified by looking at the v7 POM file that it lists support-v4 as a dependency.  So what I mentioned above is correct: because you have a dependency in your build.gradle file on appcompat-v7, you implicitly have a dependency on support-v4 and Maven/Gradle are automagically sorting it out.  That's why you're seeing the dup when you have the v4 jar file in there directly.

Comment: I got it compiling now and actually running on the mobile phone. However, it seems the map thing is not working properly. I may make a new SO entry about that.

Comment: I am getting this error "Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'

Comment: Are you running on a device which has Google Mobile Services available, so Maps is present?